# Can the Powershell runspace pool establish a remote connection and load a snap-in?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm working on a multi-tenant SharePoint provisioning application and plan to use Powershell for most of the provisioning.  I would like to use remote Powershell to invoke my cmdlets from a server that does not have SharePoint installed.  However, before I can run any of the SharePoint cmdlets the SharePoint snap-in must be loaded into the runspace.  Unfortunately, I can't find a way to provide both the connection info and the snap-in when creating the runspace pool.

Runspace pool with connection

```
    Dim connectionUrl = New Uri(String.Format("http://{0}/wsman/", remoteServer))
    Dim connectionInfo = New WSManConnectionInfo(connectionUrl)

    Me._runspacePool = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(10, 20, connectionInfo)
```

Runspace pool with snap-in

```
    Dim sessionState = InitialSessionState.Create("Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell")
    Me._runspacePool = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(sessionState)
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the directions below, you should be able to run any SharePoint cmdlets as if you were on the server.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2010/03/07/sharepoint-2010-with-windows-powershell-remoting-step-by-step.aspx

Let me know if you have any trouble setting that up...I've recently done it myself and have it working quite well.

Comment: I'm actually trying to eliminiate the overhead of creating the connection and loading the snap-in by using a runspace pool.  When I execute a new cmdlet I would like to do it with a runspace that is already connected to the remote server and that has the snap-in pre-loaded.  This is probably not usually a concern in a normal scripting scenario but I need this to be as quick as possible.  If that is not possible I may need to just create the runspace pool with the connection info and run the add-pssnapin cmdlet for all requests.

Comment: I ended up going with your proposed solution and everything is working great.  Thanks again